# How to draw vector drawable on SurfaceView's canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, drawable

My activity has setContentView with SurfaceView class.
Now I'm trying to draw VectorDrawable on this SurfaceView canvas without success, I see only black screen.

So I have some vector graphics in XML file - R.drawable.battery. It's showing correctly in Android Studio preview window.

```
public class BoardActivity extends Activity {
MySurfaceView mySurface; // My surfaceview class
Drawable vd;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mySurface = new MySurfaceView(this);
       vd = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.battery);
        setContentView(mySurface);

public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{
 Thread t;
 SurfaceHolder holder;
 boolean isItOK = false;

public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  holder = getHolder(); 
  resume();
}

@Override
public void run() {
  while(isItOK==true) {
   if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
       continue;
   }
  Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
  canvas .drawARGB(80, 188, 230, 227 ); 
  vd.draw(canvas); // draw nothing! 

  // canvas.drawRect(...   works perfect! The issue is only with vd.draw(canvas); 
  holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
}

  public void pause() {
        isItOK = false;
        while(true) {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t = null;
    }


    public void resume(){
        isItOK = true; //Starting drawing 
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Android, so I don't really know if what I will show you is good practice, but here it is:

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.battery, null);
        final SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this) {
            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                d.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
                d.draw(canvas);
            }
        };
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

This code works for me.

**Important**: did you set the background color to white? If not, I think you should do that, and if your drawable is shown correctly in the *Design* tab of Android Studio, then I think it should work in your application too.

Alternatively (and may be better) you can consider an `ImageView` and also adding it to a layout resource file. For example the main activity code can become:

```java
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

and then in the `res/layout/activity_main.xml` put:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/battery"
        android:contentDescription="@string/batteryDesc" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't forget to add a `batteryDesc` named constant in `res/values/strings.xml`.

Comment: Hello gthanop! Thank you, it works, but this is static. But I have SurfaceView in separate Thread and running run() method to update screen with 60FPS update rate (this is classical game pattern). This way d.draw(canvas) does not work.

Comment: Hi. I think you should post all your code, in your question (mainly your activity's code and the `Thread`), so that others can understand what you are looking for. Why isn't `d.draw(canvas);` not working? Have you subclassed `SurfaceView` to override its `onDraw` and paint the drawable there? What else is drawn on the `SurfaceView`? All those questions can be answered if you provide as much code of your app as possible, inside your question. Does your drawable work? Post it also in the question. Invalidating the view every 16ms does not mean you can't override `SurfaceView.onDraw` for drawable

Comment: overriding onDraw() also did not help me. I found the solution in converting my Drawable to Bitmap with bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(VectorImage.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            VectorImage.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); VectorImage.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()); VectorImage.draw(canvas); and than applying canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null); on run() method of SurfaceView. This is really strange workaround.

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, then you can answer your own question and accept it after an ammount of time has elapsed. If you need more help, you can follow the directions I have given to you already (ie post the code of your classes in the question) and also answer my questions if possible. Personally, I don't think there is a need for this workaround, but this is just my opinion. If you post your code in your question, then we might be able to provide a solution to your problem, but with just the code posted in your question I don't think you can get better help than the workaround.

Comment: I updated initial question with more or less full code setup! Please check it.

Comment: Hi. I saw your update by the time you posted it, and since then I am trying to make it work. And also I had to redesign everything because your posted code is not really complete in the post nor runnable. Anyway, the only thing that made it work was to set the bounds of the drawable before drawing it on the canvas! So make sure you set the bounds of the drawable before painting it. If that does not work, we will talk again.